# Glassfish 4.1.1 - Response code 400 on a DELETE request with a body

Tags: java, glassfish-4.1.1

According to https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21238 the fix in present in Glassfish 4.1.1.  It is applied by setting http listener property:

```
asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.allow-payload-for-undefined-http-methods=true
```

I have set this property but I still get **HTTP 400** when I invoke my delete with a request body method.

My Questions:

- Is there another setting(s) required to get this to work?
- Is this fix really in Glassfish 4.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not fixed in GF 4.1.1, see https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21238

Fix is in GF 4.1.x, https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/branches/4.1.x/nucleus/core/kernel/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/v3/services/impl/GlassfishNetworkListener.java

Regards